# Html: Background fail

Tags: html, css

I set the body to:

```
body { background-image: url(file:///Volumes/HDD/photomadness_remixed/css/Flavours_400812054.jp2);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
z-index: 0;}
```

and it displays my background but when i set this code:

```
    body {
    z-index: -1;
    background: #425b77; }
#myBody {
    background-image: url(file:///Volumes/HDD/photomadness_remixed/css/Flavours_400812054.jp2);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

it just would not display the background and instead just displaying the color i set on the body tag.
Any idea how to solve this?

Edit:
When i look at this code on another webpage i have it works correctly and i have written the exakt same thing.

This is my result from code at the second line:
[https://www.dropbox.com/s/ioo1cnfszdzh0wu/Skärmavbild%202014-03-07%20kl.%2018.44.33.png?m=](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ioo1cnfszdzh0wu/Sk%C3%A4rmavbild%202014-03-07%20kl.%2018.44.33.png?m=)

This is the result i get from the code at line 8 and downwards:
[http://www.dropbox.com/s/d8wjnwt346gzdv3/Skärmavbild%202014-03-07%20kl.%2018.44.02.png?m=](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ioo1cnfszdzh0wu/Sk%C3%A4rmavbild%202014-03-07%20kl.%2018.44.33.png?m=)

Edit:
If i add content inside the `<div id="myBody"></div>` then it will be blurred too because i want a blur filter on it.

Comment: please post your HTML or better yet a fiddle

Comment: bit of a guess ./Flavours_400812054.jp2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
body {

background: #425b77; }
#myBody {
background:url(your picture) no-repeat center center scroll;
background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
width:50%; height:50%;
display:block;
position:fixed;
z-index:1001;
```

}

this is just example... change `position` `width` and `height` as you wish

Comment: This is still not over the entire page with the blur effect and i try to position it over the page but it is just giving me a little blue border of the color i put to the body

Edit:
It worked, i just had to put the `top: 0px` and the `left: 0px` to the style!

Comment: This was even better...
My `z-index` won't co-operate with me now.

Comment: pff :) ... try to remove `z-index` in body... is it necessary `z-index` in body?

Comment: I do never use the `z-index` on the body

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `Height` and `Width` (or add the content do that div).